# inets httpd cgi script: How do you retrieve json data?

Tags: apache, erlang, cgi, inets

The cgi scripts that I have tried are unable to retrieve json data from my inets httpd server.

In order to retrieve json data in a cgi script, you need to be able to read the body of the request, which will contain something like:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

With a perl cgi script, I can read the body of a request like this:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $req_body = $cgi->param('POSTDATA');
```

I assume that is an indirect way of reading what the server pipes to the script's stdin because in a python cgi script I have to write:

```
req_body = sys.stdin.read()
```

When I request a cgi script from an `apache` server, my perl and python cgi scripts can successfully get the json data from apache. But when I request the same cgi scripts from my `inets httpd` server, my perl cgi script reads nothing for the request body, and my python cgi script hangs then the server times out.  My cgi scripts *are able* to retrieve data formatted as `"a=1&b=2"` from an `inets httpd` server--in that case the cgi facilities in both perl and python automatically parse the data for me, so instead of trying to read the body of the request, I just access the structures that cgi created.

Here is my httpd sever configuration (`server.conf`):

```
[
  {modules, [
    mod_alias,
    mod_actions,
    mod_esi,
    mod_cgi,
    mod_get,
    mod_log
  ]},
  {bind_address, "localhost"}, 
  {port,0},
  {server_name,"httpd_test"},
  {server_root,"/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj"},
  {document_root,"./htdocs"},
  {script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/", "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/cgi-bin/"} },
  {erl_script_alias, {"/erl", [mymod]} },
  {erl_script_nocache, true},
  {error_log, "./errors.log"},
  {transfer_log, "./requests.log"}
].
```

I start my httpd server with this program (`s.erl`):

```
-module(s).
-compile(export_all).

%Need to look up port with httpd:info(Server)

ensure_inets_start() ->
    case inets:start() of
        ok -> ok;
        {error,{already_started,inets}} -> ok
    end.

start() ->
    ok = ensure_inets_start(),

    {ok, Server} = inets:start(httpd, 
        [{proplist_file, "./server.conf"}]
    ),
    Server.

stop(Server) ->
    ok = inets:stop(httpd, Server).
```

My cgi script (`1.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()  #errors to browser
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: text/html")
sys.stdout.write("\r\n\r\n")

#print("<div>hello</div>")

req_body = sys.stdin.read()
my_dict = json.loads(req_body)

if my_dict:
    a = my_dict.get("a", "Not found")
    b = my_dict.get("b", "Not found")
    total = a + b
    print("<div>Got json: {}</div>".format(my_dict) )
    print("<div>a={}, b={}, total={}</div>".format(a, b, total))
else:
    print("<div>Couldn't read json data.</div>")
```

My cgi script (`1.pl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use JSON;

my $q = CGI->new;

print $q->header,
      $q->start_html("Test Page"),
      $q->h1("Results:"),
      $q->div("json=$json"),
      $q->end_html;
```

Server startup in terminal window:

```
~/erlang_programs/inets_proj$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.2  (abort with ^G)

1> c(s).              
s.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,s}

2> Server = s:start().
<0.86.0>

3> httpd:info(Server).
[{mime_types,[{"htm","text/html"},{"html","text/html"}]},
 {server_name,"httpd_test"},
 {erl_script_nocache,true},
 {script_alias,{"/cgi-bin/",
                "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/cgi-bin/"}},
 {bind_address,{127,0,0,1}},
 {modules,[mod_alias,mod_actions,mod_esi,mod_cgi,mod_get,
           mod_log]},
 {server_root,"/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj"},
 {erl_script_alias,{"/erl",[mymod]}},
 {port,51301},
 {transfer_log,<0.93.0>},
 {error_log,<0.92.0>},
 {document_root,"./htdocs"}]
4>
```

curl request:

```
$ curl -v \
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> --data '{"a": 1, "b": 2}' \
> http://localhost:51301/cgi-bin/1.py

*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 51301 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 51301 (#0)
> POST /cgi-bin/1.py HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:51301
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 16
> 
* upload completely sent off: 16 out of 16 bytes

===== hangs for about 5 seconds ====

< HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
< Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 11:02:27 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: inets/6.4.5
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
< 
* Closing connection 0
$
```

My directory structure:

```
~/erlang_programs$ tree inets_proj/
inets_proj/
├── apache_cl.erl
├── cgi-bin
│   ├── 1.pl
│   └── 1.py
├── cl.beam
├── cl.erl
├── errors.log
├── htdocs
│   └── file1.txt
├── mylog.log
├── mymod.beam
├── mymod.erl
├── old_server.conf
├── old_server3.conf
├── old_server4.conf
├── requests.log
├── s.beam
├── s.erl
├── server.conf
└── urlencoded_post_cl.erl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug up the RFC for the cgi spec, which says:

```
RFC 3875                    CGI Version 1.1                 October 2004


4.2.  Request Message-Body

   Request data is accessed by the script in a system-defined method;
   unless defined otherwise, this will be by reading the 'standard
   input' file descriptor or file handle.

      Request-Data   = [ request-body ] [ extension-data ]
      request-body   = <CONTENT_LENGTH>OCTET
      extension-data = *OCTET

   A request-body is supplied with the request if the CONTENT_LENGTH is
   not NULL.  The server MUST make at least that many bytes available
   for the script to read.  The server MAY signal an end-of-file
   condition after CONTENT_LENGTH bytes have been read or it MAY supply
   extension data.  Therefore, the script MUST NOT attempt to read more
   than CONTENT_LENGTH bytes, even if more data is available.  However,
   it is not obliged to read any of the data.
```

I don't understand what *extension data* is, but the key line is:

> the [cgi] script MUST NOT attempt to read more than CONTENT_LENGTH
>   bytes, even if more data is available.

If I alter my python script to read in the content length rather than trying to read in the whole stdin file--which doesn't stop reading until it gets an eof signal--then my python cgi script successfully retrieves the json data from my inets httpd server.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import sys
import os

content_len = int(os.environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"])

req_body = sys.stdin.read(content_len)
my_dict = json.loads(req_body)

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: text/html")
sys.stdout.write("\r\n\r\n")

if my_dict:
    a = my_dict.get("a", "Not found")
    b = my_dict.get("b", "Not found")
    total = a + b
    print("<div>Content-Length={}</div".format(content_len))
    print("<div>Got json: {}</div>".format(my_dict) )
    print("<div>a={}, b={}, total={}</div>".format(a, b, total))
else:
    print("<div>Couldn't read json data.</div>")

'''
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if "a" not in form:
    print("<H1>Error:</H1>")
    print("<div>'a' not in form</div>")
else:
    print("<p>a:{}</p>".format( form["a"].value) )


if "b" not in form:
    print("<H1>Error:</H1>")
    print("<div>'b' not in form</div>")
else:
    print("<p>b:{}</p>".format(form["b"].value) )
'''
```

Server info:

```
4> httpd:info(Server).
[{mime_types,[{"htm","text/html"},{"html","text/html"}]},
 {server_name,"httpd_test"},
 {erl_script_nocache,true},
 {script_alias,{"/cgi-bin/",
                "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/cgi-bin/"}},
 {bind_address,{127,0,0,1}},
 {modules,[mod_alias,mod_actions,mod_esi,mod_cgi,mod_get,
           mod_log]},
 {server_root,"/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj"},
 {erl_script_alias,{"/erl",[mymod]}},
 {port,65451},
 {transfer_log,<0.93.0>},
 {error_log,<0.92.0>},
 {document_root,"./htdocs"}]
5>
```

curl request (note that curl automatically calculates the content length and puts it in a Content-Length header):

```
~$ curl -v \
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> --data '{"a": 1, "b": 2}' \
> http://localhost:65451/cgi-bin/1.py

*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 65451 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 65451 (#0)
> POST /cgi-bin/1.py HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:65451
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 16
> 
* upload completely sent off: 16 out of 16 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 09 Mar 2018 04:36:42 GMT
< Server: inets/6.4.5
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
<div>Content-Length=16</div
<div>Got json: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}</div>
<div>a=1, b=2, total=3</div>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
~$
```

Here's the perl script that I got work with inets httpd (`1.pl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

if (my $content_len = $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH}) {

    read(STDIN, my $json, $content_len);
    my $href = decode_json($json);
    my $a = $href->{a};
    my $b = $href->{b};

    print 'Content-type: text/html';
    print "\r\n\r\n";
    print "<div>a=$a</div>";
    print "<div>b=$b</div>";

    #my $q = CGI->new; #Doesn't work with inets httpd server
    #my $q = CGI->new(''); #Doesn't try to read from stdin, do does work.

    #  print $q->header,
    #    $q->start_html("Test Page"),
    #    $q->div("json=$json"),
    #    $q->div("a=$a"),
    #    $q->div("b=$b"),
    #    $q->div("total=$total"),
    #    $q->end_html;
} 
else {
    my $error = "Could not read json: No Content-Length header in request.";
    print 'Content-type: text/html';
    print "\r\n\r\n";
    print "<div>$error</div>";


    #   my $q = CGI->new;
    #   print $q->header,
    #         $q->start_html("Test Page"),
    #         $q->h1($error),
    #         $q->end_html;
}
```

I couldn't get perl's CGI module to work in conjunction with reading from STDIN.  **Edit:** A kind soul at perlmonks helped me solve that one:

```
my $q = CGI->new('');
```

The blank string tells CGI->new not to read from stdin and parse the data.